# Error compiling with Visual Studio 2013 using VisualMicro addon for Arduino

Tags: visual-studio, arduino-uno

I am trying to compile sketch for Arduino, using VisualMicro addon for Visual Studio 2013. But even if I try to compile empty project, I  have error I cannot understand. What is the source of the problem?

```
Compiling 'Test' for 'Arduino Uno'
Process: "{runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}\bin\avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=163 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" -I"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Just_a_human\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\Test\uno\Test.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Just_a_human\AppData\Local\V.Micro\Arduino\Builds\Test\uno\Test.cpp.o" Error compiling
```

Could anyone please show me  in which direction I have to dig?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was due to the fact that VisualMicro doesn't support Arduino 1.6.2+ yet. I had to read manuals better ;)

Answer (score 0):

What's version of your Arduino? If your Arduino version is 1.6.3 +, you need to use Visual Micro beta since Visual Micro stable supports for Arduino 1.6.1 or earlier. This works fine for me, so check your Arduino version.
   Here's download link for Visual Micro: http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Arduino-Visual-Studio-Downloads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual Micro 1.6.2 support was released a short time after Arduino released it. There were some huge changes but it should all be working well now :)

This error can also happen if Arduino 1.6.6+ has not been run at least once after install.